# Chef MySQL cookbook deprecation warnings

Tags: mysql, chef-infra, chef-recipe

When using the current mysql 8.4.0 cookbook I receive a full screen of deprecation errors when deploying.

```
Deprecated features used!
  rename install_method to new_resource.install_method at 1 location:
    - /root/chef-solo/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/mysql_service.rb:34:in `installation'
   See https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_namespace_collisions.html for further details.
```

The github project does not show any outstanding issues related to the deprecation warnings.

Does anyone know how to get rid of these messages so I can have a clean deploy?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to wait until the cookbook fixes things, but it's only a warning so you don't need to worry. It's a new warning in Chef 13.2 so we're still working on getting things cleaned up. The feature won't actually be removed until Chef 14 in April 2018 so no rush :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know its just a warning but it doesn't look too nice when you have a full screen of them. I'll keep my eye out for the updates.

Comment: You might want to trail a version of two on Chef itself if this is a concern :)